# react-table pagination properties doesn't exist on type 'TableInstance{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pagination, frontend, react-table

I'm trying to implement a pagination using react-table. In most tutorials we start with this:

```
const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        page,
        prepareRow,
        visibleColumns,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
            initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 10 },
        },
```

In my case, my IDE says, that the properties:
page,
canPreviousPage,
canNextPage,
pageOptions,
pageCount,
gotoPage,
nextPage,
previousPage,
setPageSize

doesn't exist on type 'TableInstance{}'.

After a lot of research in the www, I can't find a reason why these properties aren't in the TableInstance.
How can I use the pagination without these properties or is there a way to make it work?

I look forward to every answer

Comment: Can you share a link to tutorial you're using?

Comment: ofc, this one https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/pagination

Comment: The main problem is that TS types are incorrect! If you check ```index.d.ts``` file in ```@types/react-table``` you'll see, for example, ```setPageSize``` property only declared within ```UsePaginationInstanceProps``` and ```UsePaginationInstanceProps``` doesn't used elsewhere.

Comment: Possibly, maintainers of this package doesn't update types yet while package itself was moved to new version.

Answer (score 46):

Creating a `react-table-config.d.ts` file with the following content fixed the issue for me:

```
import {
  UseColumnOrderInstanceProps,
  UseColumnOrderState,
  UseExpandedHooks,
  UseExpandedInstanceProps,
  UseExpandedOptions,
  UseExpandedRowProps,
  UseExpandedState,
  UseFiltersColumnOptions,
  UseFiltersColumnProps,
  UseFiltersInstanceProps,
  UseFiltersOptions,
  UseFiltersState,
  UseGlobalFiltersColumnOptions,
  UseGlobalFiltersInstanceProps,
  UseGlobalFiltersOptions,
  UseGlobalFiltersState,
  UseGroupByCellProps,
  UseGroupByColumnOptions,
  UseGroupByColumnProps,
  UseGroupByHooks,
  UseGroupByInstanceProps,
  UseGroupByOptions,
  UseGroupByRowProps,
  UseGroupByState,
  UsePaginationInstanceProps,
  UsePaginationOptions,
  UsePaginationState,
  UseResizeColumnsColumnOptions,
  UseResizeColumnsColumnProps,
  UseResizeColumnsOptions,
  UseResizeColumnsState,
  UseRowSelectHooks,
  UseRowSelectInstanceProps,
  UseRowSelectOptions,
  UseRowSelectRowProps,
  UseRowSelectState,
  UseRowStateCellProps,
  UseRowStateInstanceProps,
  UseRowStateOptions,
  UseRowStateRowProps,
  UseRowStateState,
  UseSortByColumnOptions,
  UseSortByColumnProps,
  UseSortByHooks,
  UseSortByInstanceProps,
  UseSortByOptions,
  UseSortByState
} from 'react-table'

declare module 'react-table' {
  // take this file as-is, or comment out the sections that don't apply to your plugin configuration

  export interface TableOptions<D extends Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseExpandedOptions<D>,
      UseFiltersOptions<D>,
      UseGlobalFiltersOptions<D>,
      UseGroupByOptions<D>,
      UsePaginationOptions<D>,
      UseResizeColumnsOptions<D>,
      UseRowSelectOptions<D>,
      UseRowStateOptions<D>,
      UseSortByOptions<D>,
      // note that having Record here allows you to add anything to the options, this matches the spirit of the
      // underlying js library, but might be cleaner if it's replaced by a more specific type that matches your
      // feature set, this is a safe default.
      Record<string, any> {}

  export interface Hooks<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseExpandedHooks<D>,
      UseGroupByHooks<D>,
      UseRowSelectHooks<D>,
      UseSortByHooks<D> {}

  export interface TableInstance<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseColumnOrderInstanceProps<D>,
      UseExpandedInstanceProps<D>,
      UseFiltersInstanceProps<D>,
      UseGlobalFiltersInstanceProps<D>,
      UseGroupByInstanceProps<D>,
      UsePaginationInstanceProps<D>,
      UseRowSelectInstanceProps<D>,
      UseRowStateInstanceProps<D>,
      UseSortByInstanceProps<D> {}

  export interface TableState<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseColumnOrderState<D>,
      UseExpandedState<D>,
      UseFiltersState<D>,
      UseGlobalFiltersState<D>,
      UseGroupByState<D>,
      UsePaginationState<D>,
      UseResizeColumnsState<D>,
      UseRowSelectState<D>,
      UseRowStateState<D>,
      UseSortByState<D> {}

  export interface ColumnInterface<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseFiltersColumnOptions<D>,
      UseGlobalFiltersColumnOptions<D>,
      UseGroupByColumnOptions<D>,
      UseResizeColumnsColumnOptions<D>,
      UseSortByColumnOptions<D> {}

  export interface ColumnInstance<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseFiltersColumnProps<D>,
      UseGroupByColumnProps<D>,
      UseResizeColumnsColumnProps<D>,
      UseSortByColumnProps<D> {}

  export interface Cell<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>, V = any>
    extends UseGroupByCellProps<D>,
      UseRowStateCellProps<D> {}

  export interface Row<D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
    extends UseExpandedRowProps<D>,
      UseGroupByRowProps<D>,
      UseRowSelectRowProps<D>,
      UseRowStateRowProps<D> {}
}
```

As suggested in:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: OP and @Muzaffer, I have created the file under @types/react-table but the issue still maintains, is it enought to just create this file?

Comment: Where did you put this file? Your project or node_modules/@types/react-table?

Comment: Where this file should be placed?

Comment: It should work anywhere your project can detect the file. The doc suggest putting it in the root or in the types folder

Comment: I have that file in my root folder but it doesn't help. Should I change something in imports where I'm importing `react-table` or something? When I'm mouseover that impot it shows types from node_modules

Comment: I get errors in this declaration file on pretty much every interface

Answer (score 1):

It is not really "the best" answer out there, perhaps. However, if you wanna run `npm build` you cannot **unless you "fix" the missing type error**. What I did is simply put `@ts-ignore` above the underlined pieces of code. It goes something like this:

```
    // @ts-ignore
    nextPage
```