# React: declaration merging for react-table types doesn't work. Property doesn't exist on type 'TableInstance'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm facing an odd issue while implementing pagination for my `react-table` component. The problem is what you can see in the screenshot - `Property X does not exist on type 'TableInstance`:

[image]

So I found a similar problem that someone had before and I have used the approved solution: [react-table pagination properties doesn't exist on type 'TableInstance{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608974/react-table-pagination-properties-doesnt-exist-on-type-tableinstance)

The example file is also here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table#example-type-file

The problem is that nothing has changed, I have described the file in the root folder and it seems that APP can't see it as you can see in the picture above.

[image]

I'm new to React, can someone help me with that? I was trying to find a solution by myself but I failed :(

Comment: It looks like you're using typescript. If so, most libs have a type definitions file. So after you install `reaact'table`. Search for and install the types. Usually starts with `@types/...`  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-table. No need to create a `.d.ts` file from scratch

Comment: Yes I know @SakoBu I have it, but the problem still occures.. That's why there is that "workaround" with DefinitelyTyped stuff..

Comment: Probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608974/react-table-pagination-properties-doesnt-exist-on-type-tableinstance

Answer (score 1):

Just [add a triple-slash directive path](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-path-) pointing to the [`react-table-config.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table#example-type-file) file so the types get augmented. It's going to be something like this:

```js
/// <reference path="./react-table-config.d.ts" />
```

Including it in one place is already enough. No need to add it to every file that uses `react-table`.

Comment: react-table-config.d.ts can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66731727/8198873

Comment: Where should I put it? I tried with App.tsx and there with imports and inside of main function but in both case it failed. Or maybe I need to run some script or something to make it works?

Comment: In the `App.tsx` is enough. Just notice the `react-table-config.d.ts` path should be relative to `App.tsx`. Something like `"../../react-table-config.d.ts"` if `App.tsx` is located at `src/components/App.tsx`